# PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql

Since my host updated the server to php 8.1 from 7.4 i have been having nothing but issues but this one has me stumped. I keep getting the following error

> PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client.
> Please, report to the developers in
> /home/*****/*****/app/Helpers/Database.php on line 62

This is line 62

```
$instance = new self("$type:host=$host;dbname=$name;default-character-set=utf8", $user, $pass);
```

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance

I've tried removing the charset but still get the error

Comment: I changed it from character=utf8 to default-character-set=utf8 as the post suggested but the error still occurs

Comment: Have you restarted mysqld? What's the mysqld version?